# Adapt Datagrid Number Column WPF

Tags: wpf

I want to adapt/resize my datagrid with the number of cells. I have a empty column. Can someone help me ?

[image]

Comment: Can you add more specifics on what size you want to achieve or what should be the desired result

Comment: It's ok ! I added the "*" for ColumnWidth and it works ! Thanks. Close the subject